# Find bug in my Knight's Move Python Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, breadth-first-search, knights-tour

### Code

I am trying to build a Knight's Move Program everything working fine but there is a hidden bug in this code that I cannot find. Can anybody spot the problem?

```
from itertools import product
def solution(src, dest):
    A = [[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
         [8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
         [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
         [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
         [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
         [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
         [56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]]
    if (src not in range(0,64) or dest not in range(0,64)) :
        raise Exception('out of range')
    step = 1
    r_s = 0
    r_e = 7
    str_r = 0
    str_c = 0
    while src:
        if r_s <= src <= r_e:
            for i in range(0, 8):
                if A[str_r][i] == src:
                    str_c = i
                    break
            break
        str_r += 1
        r_s += 8
        r_e += 8
    moves = list(product([str_r - 1, str_r + 1], [str_c - 2, str_c + 2])) + list(product([str_r - 2, str_r + 2],[str_c - 1, str_c + 1]))
    m_s = [(x,y) for x,y in moves if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < 8 and y < 8]
    for i, j in m_s:
        if A[i][j] == dest:
            move_counter = step
            return move_counter
    while True:
        step += 1
        List_steps = []
        for i, j in m_s:
            r_s = 0
            r_e = 7
            str_r = 0
            str_c = 0
            while True:
                if r_s <= A[i][j] <= r_e:
                    for x in range(0, 8):
                        if A[str_r][x] == A[i][j]:
                            str_c = x
                            break
                    break
                str_r += 1
                r_s += 8
                r_e += 8
            moves = list(product([str_r - 1, str_r + 1], [str_c - 2, str_c + 2])) + list(product([str_r - 2, str_r + 2],[str_c - 1, str_c + 1]))
            m_z = [(x,y) for x,y in moves if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < 8 and y < 8]
            for m, n in m_z:
                if A[m][n] == dest:
                    return step
            move_counter = 'Not Found'
            List_steps += m_z
        if move_counter == 'Not Found':
            m_s = list(set(List_steps))
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = int(input())
    B = int(input())
    print(solution(A, B))
```

---

### Bug Location

I think the bug is here:

```
moves = list(product([str_r - 1, str_r + 1], [str_c - 2, str_c + 2])) + list(product([str_r - 2, str_r + 2],[str_c - 1, str_c + 1]))
m_z = [(x,y) for x,y in moves if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < 8 and y < 8]
```

Comment: why are you sure that there's a bug ? are u experiencing any issues ? if so u need to inform the issue you are facing, you can't expect people to go through your code just coz u feel there's a bug !

Comment: have you run this program?

Comment: sometimes it gives intended output and sometimes not :(

Comment: then you need to specify what is the incorrect output you are getting, and the output you expect to get

Comment: Check the output at 0, 63 it should be 6 but its returning 4

Comment: add this to the question instead of the comments so people can understand the problem better

Comment: Please add the desired and observed behavior to the question!

Comment: The bug in this program is probably that it doesn't return zero when the start and end squares are the same

Comment: Further to the above, you would do well to start with your "visited" list `m_s` set to just the source square, and `step = 0`. This would also eliminate a repeated piece of code, since the action you take on the first step looks just like the action you take on subsequent steps.  Also, as a hint, you might find  `row,col = divmod(src,8)` useful.